# Updateing package by sudo command in 13.04

Tags: command-line, updates

I used the `sudo` command in terminal to update the software after upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 and it gave me this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-docs_13.04.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas what this means and what is the next step to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install`  then try to update again. From:http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/